# How to update a sideloaded uwp app? (what's the best pratice for doing that)

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, distribution, visual-studio-app-center

We distributed a uwp app on a remote PC and now have a breaking change and need to force the client to update. The app is not in the microsoft store, as it was mainly installed with the installation file directly transfered to the PC. For future releases we now need a possibility to let the client know that there is a new version available, he must install.

What's the best practice for doing this?

Comment: [Sideload LOB apps in Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10): *"You maintain the signing, hosting, and deployment of these apps."* That's the feature description. With developer-tainted glasses it reads differently: *"You are responsible for ..."* That's the gist of it. You stepped outside Microsoft's deployment infrastructure, and that has become your liability now. There aren't any best practices other than [not doing it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-apps-from-your-private-store).

Comment: We initially were using AppCenter, but we realised that we also can't inform the user about a new version via this way. We also thought about using a private Microsoft App Store, but somehow found out that Microsoft will discontinue this feature. So I am wondering what the Microsoft deployment infrastructure for an UWP App is?